# mmap fails with ENOMEM

Tags: linux, unix, mmap

I use `mmap()` in our application as:

```
 mmap(NULL, get_size(), PROT_NONE,  MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

But my intention here is just to reserve `get_size()` speicified amount of memory, but I don't intend to use it. Sometimes I see this `mmap()` fails with ENOMEM. The question is why `mmap()` should fail with `ENOMEM` here, when we just try to reserve the address space but not trying to actually use it. Is it because of `MAP_SHARED`?

Comment: What is the size you pass to `mmap`? Dump the process memory map with `map -x <pid>` and post it here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit on virtual memory size of a process which you can see with `ulimit -v`. If you are hitting that limit you can try removing it with `ulimit -v unlimited`. You can also get and set the limit programmatically with `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` POSIX functions.

The system default and hard limits are set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and files from directory `/etc/security/limits.d`.

---

Another reason `mmap` fails with `ENOMEM` is exceeding the maximum number of memory mappings for a process controlled by `vm.max_map_count` configuration option of `sysctl`.